# How to use a different mirror of macports rather than the offical mirrors?

Tags: macos, macports

How to use a different mirror rather than the mirrors in the [list](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Mirrors)?

Well, I mean not only download `port.tar` from other mirror, like the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693375/how-to-change-the-mirror-of-macports), but also download packages from a different mirror.

I have noticed that when downloading packages, the `port` just download packages from [this link](http://jog.id.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/). But I don't know how to change the mirror it get packages from.

Many thanks!

I will appreciate every answer or comment.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693375/how-to-change-the-mirror-of-macports

Comment: @KeithSmiley If it is duplicate, I would not ask it again. The [ustc](http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/macports/) mirror has only the ports files, but I am asking a different question. You can check the links in my question to know it is not DUPLICATE. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: That SO question and http://superuser.com/questions/473186/how-to-change-macports-default-mirrors will work for any mirror just use the path. But Macports is only on the mirrors on that list - where do you want to read it from

Comment: @Mark From a computer in my University. I am to setup a mirror for me and other students. A case as I have noticed is that, even if I have downloaded the tar.gz or zip file and I put it in the right location, It will also download from the given mirror.

Comment: If you have a mirror like that then just rsync the whole lot or ask the system administrators how they maintain the computers and use that tool

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I will try to contact them. It is really a good idea than to ask here than directly contact them.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you wanted to use a mirror for the [binary archive](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.binaries.html#using.binaries.archives) , while the [linked question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693375/how-to-change-the-mirror-of-macports) is only about the port metadata. So instead of looking at `/opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf`, you should be looking at `archive_sites.conf` under the same folder. The default content of that file is at [GitHub](https://github.com/macports/macports-base/blob/3c0f70bb7d5b5e311538806022318a06d6e3c623/doc/archive_sites.conf); see the file comments for usage.